# Codeigniter batch update performance

Tags: mysql, database, performance, codeigniter

Does `$this->db->update_batch();` update with 1 table connection or does it update each row separately incurring overhead of opening connections?

I'm wondering if this is faster than using foreach and `$this->db->update();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in Codeigniter documentation `$this->db->update_batch();` generate a single query and establish only one connection. So it would be faster than query within `foreach` loop.

After profiling I can see following results (only `0.0700 sec` taken to update 4 rows)

[image: UPDATE batch]

on other hand I have updated same no. of rows with loop and it takes much time (`0.665 sec` which is almost 1 sec)

[image: foreach loop]

Comment: awesome! hope this helps other people too! :)